# Entity Framework Modeling - How to model this simple data structure?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-mapping

[image: Data Structure]

This is a relatively simple data structure, but I am having a hard time figuring out the best EF strategy to model it. It's obviously not Table Per Hierarchy. So I tried Table Per Type and it didn't like the relationships between Client and Person or Customer and Person. After reading about Table Per Concrete Type, it doesn't follow that model either. S how would one model this ERD?

#

Update

#

The business use case behind it is that we deal with several companies. Some of these companies have purchased other companies. The parent company (Acme) has been a long time customer. The child company (Zeta) has been a long time client. When Acme bought Zeta they put one person in charge of handling the relationships between the company (Adam). Adam now has 2 distinct email addresses that need to be notified of events. adam@acme.com gets customer notifications. adam@zeta.com gets client notifications. That was the reason I had it modeled like it was. Adam is a bit OCD and likes to keep his notifications separated into individual mailboxes. As a programmer, I don't like Adam. :D

There are several other classifications in the system than Client and Customer. We also have Vendors, Technicians, and Distributors. I ended up modeling it very similar to the below suggestion, but split the Email table into type specific tables (CustomerEmail and ClientEmail). Not perfect but in order to just "get it done", it works.

Comment: A person can be both a client and a customer. A person can be a notator (person writing the note) or a notatee (person about which the note is written). Notes can be written by Clients about Customers or vice versa.

Comment: Why isn't there just one association between Person an Email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A person can be both a client and a customer.

Then `Client` and `Customer` cannot inherit from `Person`. You must model this with composition. **Not**: A `Person` **is a** `Client` or `Customer`. **Instead**: A `Person` **has an** attribute to be a `Client` and/or `Customer`.

With EF this would be two one-to-one relationships:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

`Client` and `Customer` can have a `Person` reference refering back to `Person`. (They don't need to have this reference but it makes sense to enable access to the FirstName and LastName via this navigation property.)

```
public class Client / Customer
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I assume that a Person doesn't need to have always *both* a `Client` and a `Customer` attribute, but sometimes only one (or even zero?). In this case `Person` is the principal in both relationships and `Client`/`Customer` are the dependents: They **must** have a reference to a `Person`, but the `Person` only has **optional** references to `Client` and `Customer`. With Fluent API this would be modeled like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Client)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Person);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.Customer)
    .WithRequired(c => c.Person);
```

The relationships between `Person` and `Note` are two ordinary one-to-many relationships. `Person` can have two navigation collections...

```
public ICollection<Note> NotesAsNotator { get; set; }
public ICollection<Note> NotesAsNotatee { get; set; }
```

...and `Note` can have two references to `Person` together with the two foreign key properties (they are not required to be exposed in the model but often helpful):

```
public int NotatorIDFK { get; set; }
public Person Notator { get; set; }

public int NotateeIDFK { get; set; }
public Person Notatee { get; set; }
```

And the relationships are defined with Fluent API as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.NotesAsNotator)
    .WithRequired(n => n.Notator)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.NotatorIDFK)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.NotesAsNotatee)
    .WithRequired(n => n.Notatee)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.NotateeIDFK)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Cascading delete must the disabled here (at least for one of the two relationships), otherwise `Person` can delete `Notes` through more than one cascading delete path due to the two relationships which is - at least in SQL Server - forbidden.

The relationships between `Location` and `Client` and between `Location` and `Customer` are again two one-to-many relationships each (four in total) with four collections in `Location` and two references to `Location` in `Client` and `Customer`. They are modeled similarly to the relationships above.

The relationships between `Client` and `Email` and `Customer` and `Email` are a problem because they are one-to-one but apparently with a foreign key `PersonIDFK` (with unique key constraint?) which is not supported by EF. As already asked by Gert Arnold in the comments: Why isn't the relationship between `Person` and `Email`? Are the two relationships supposed to express that a person can have another email address as a client than as a customer? I don't understand this part of the model.